# Django Rest Framework Filter related model by lookup_field (uuid) in DRF instead of pk

Tags: django, rest, filter, frameworks

I have two django models that are related.
Let's call these two models `book` and `author`.
For simplification let's assume it's a one to one relation.

I am using the Django Rest Framework lookup_field to make the basic api calls, using uuid instead of pk as shown here. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

so The API calls I have are `/books/e56c231c-0a11-48fa-ab6a-dcdae0a53620/`
and `/authors/e56c231c-0a11-48fa-ab6a-dcdae0a53620/` instead of `/books/1/` and `/authors/1/` where 1 is the pk.

This works great so far.

However Now I am implementing the DRF filtering feature. And the filtering by default works as follows. `/books?author=1` This works great, but I don't want the pks to be exposed. I would like the filtering to be working like this `/books?author=e56c231c-0a11-48fa-ab6a-dcdae0a53620/`

I was able to get it working by doing `/books?author__uuid=e56c231c-0a11-48fa-ab6a-dcdae0a53620/` but this is not what I am looking for. 
I would really like the UI generated by the drf filters to include the UUID as the values as well, instead of pk.

Thank you

Comment: Could you show the code of your view function / class?

Comment: You could use [filter_set](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html#adding-a-filterset-with-filterset-class) class of django-filter package